# How to make fixed sidebar scrollable through the main scroll without introducing another scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have the a side bar that have the following style

```
.side-bar{
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Right now since this sidebar is vertically longer than screen length, the browser introduces another vertical scroll right next to the side bar.

This is not ideal.

Is there a way to control both the main content and the side bar with the same vertical scroll?

Comment: one way is to define , width of the sidebar or if it is directly inside body , use width:100%  and overflow:hidden

Comment: If your intent is to use the main scroll bar to scroll both the side bar and the main page, why did you introduce a div-specific scroll bar (using overflow:auto) to begin with? If you want the div to scroll with the page, why did you use position:fixed? Can you fully describe the behavior you're after?  Are you asking for the main scroll bar to scroll the page and the div at the same time?  Or are you thinking the main scroll bar would scroll the main page some of the time and the div some of the time? If the latter, how would the browser know which of these the user wanted?

Comment: @RandallStewart I want a fixed side bar on the side of the screen, but the side bar is longer than the length of the browser, so I want it to be scrollable, but I don't want to introduce another scroll bar for controlling the side bar, but rather have the main scroll bar scrolling both the fixed side bar and the content.

Comment: @RandallStewart  Its possible, facebook's personal page have a side bar that is scrollable using the main scroll, I am looking at it right now, although I have trouble understanding how they implemented it. The style of the fixed bar is fixed. The side bar is also always longer than screen, but its scrollable using the main scroll bar.

Comment: @testing: Can you make the main page scroll?  If not, it's possible the scroll bar you're seeing is the scroll bar of the side bar itself, and that the scroll bar of the browser window has been disabled by setting the body overflow to none (and maybe body height to 100%).  I wonder if that is what Naga Sai was getting at in the first comment?

Comment: @testing Both the side bar and the content is longer than screen in the facebook page I mentioned.  I tried setting the height to 100% and overflow to none, or other combinations, but none of it works.

Comment: @ testing: My mistake, body overflow should be "hidden" rather none.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120183/discussion-between-randall-stewart-and-testing).

Answer (score 1):

Can you see if this is the effect you're looking for?  For simplicity, it shows only 1 element (a div) that serves as the right-sided, fixed bar.  This setup gives you one scroll bar, but the scroll bar belongs to the div only.  The body of the page itself is not scrollable, so if the body has too much content, the overflow will not be visible.

To test the small sample below, you'll want to add a bunch of text to the div to force it to expand vertically.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
      border: dotted 1px #00ff00;
    }
    div {
      float:right;
      margin: 0 0 0 2em;
      max-height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 5em;
      border: dotted 1px #ff0000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    This is the scrollable side bar. Add a bunch of text here to force the height to expand.
  </div>

  This is the main body. If you add a bunch of text here, you'll see how the overflow is cut off and a 2nd scroll bar does not appear.
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the explanation of the CSS...

BODY ELEMENT

- **overflow:hidden** Prevents the a scroll bar from appearing on the main page.
- **height:100%** Sets the body height to match the window height.
- **border:dotted 1px #00ff00**  Only added to show the perimeter of the body element more clearly.

DIV ELEMENT

- **float:right** Moves div to top right of page.  You could also use fixed positioning, but this keeps the body content from flowing underneath the div.
- **margin:0 0 0 2em** Keeps div from getting too close to body content.
- **max-height:100%** Makes sure the bar can't expand more than the window height, forcing a scroll bar to appear
- **overflow:auto** Causes the div to show a scroll bar when the div content exceeds the div height
- **width:5em** Prevents the div from filling the entire width of the window
- **border:dotted 1px #ff0000** Shows the boundaries of the div

EDIT:
The original CSS above works in quirks mode, but scroll bars fail to appear with an HTML5 doctype.  The fix is to use fixed positioning rather than floating.  Or to set an absolute height on the side-bar div (rather than a percentage of the body height) so the that height of the side bar doesn't depend on the height of the body element.

I think the problem is this: The body element has an overflow of "hidden" to prevent scroll bars from appearing.  However, an element with overflow other than visible will expand vertically, as needed, to contain any floated content.  Therefore the "max-height:100%" on the side-bar div is meaningless, because the body element will expand to be whatever height the div needs. Using fixed positioning on the div prevents the body from expanding without limit to contain a floated element.  Or, using an absolute div height, constrains the height of a floated div even when the body element can't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used the same style in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yzH0jlPYTVowwpKxOG31?p=preview) but I see that there is no scroll bar at all for both content and side bar